# C++ not getting all lines from .txt file when tokenising

Tags: c++, text-files, ifstream

I am trying to read in my text file that contains book list.
However, when I output the file that I read in, I found there is some left out.
I'm wondering if the problem is happening when I try to tokenise the file.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

typedef struct
{
    int shelf;
    int level;
} LOCATION_TYPE;

typedef struct
{
    char isbn[14];
    char author[40];
    char title[40];
    char publisher[40];
    int year;
    char genre[20];
    char price[10];
    char quantity[3];
    LOCATION_TYPE location;

} BOOK_TYPE;

void menu();
void list(BOOK_TYPE book[], int total_book);
void search(BOOK_TYPE students[], int total_student);

int main(void)
{
    BOOK_TYPE book[100];
    ifstream input("booklist.txt"); // read input from a text file.
    if (!input)  // check error.
    {
        cout << "Error opening file.\n";
        exit(100); // testing if the text file is connected
    }
    else
    {

        char delim[] = ",";
        char temp[100];
        int index = -1, choice;

        input.getline(temp, 100, '\n');

        while(input)
        {
            char* token = strtok(temp, delim);

            strcpy(book[++index].isbn, token);
            strcpy(book[index].author, strtok(NULL, delim));
            strcpy(book[index].title, strtok(NULL, delim));
            strcpy(book[index].publisher, strtok(NULL, delim));
            book[index].year = atoi(strtok(NULL, delim));
            strcpy(book[index].price, strtok(NULL, delim));
            strcpy(book[index].quantity, strtok(NULL, delim));
            book[index].location.shelf = atoi(strtok(NULL, delim));
            book[index].location.level = atoi(strtok(NULL, delim));
            strcpy(book[index].genre, strtok(NULL, delim));

            // clear unwanted whitespace
            if (input.peek() == '\n')
                input.ignore(256, '\n');

            // read next number
            input.getline(temp, 100, '\n');
            //token = strtok(book[++index], delim);
        }
        input.close();

        system("cls");
        menu();
        cin >> choice;
        while (choice != 0)
        {
            if (choice == 1)
            {
                list(book, index);
            }

            else if (choice == 2)
            {
                search(book, index);
            }

            else
            {
                system("cls");
                cout << "Invalid input. Please key in number 0-4.\n";
                system("pause");
            }
            system("cls");
            menu();
            cin >> choice;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void menu()
{
    cout << "UNDERGROUND BOOKS" << endl;
    cout << "1. List all books record" << endl;
    cout << "2. Search books" << endl;
    cout << "3. Add books" << endl;
    cout << "4. Delete books" << endl;
    cout << "0. Exit" << endl;
    cout << "What would you like to do?" << endl;
}

void list(BOOK_TYPE book[], int total_book)
{
    system("cls");
    for (int i = 0; i < total_book; i++)
    {
        cout << left << setw(15) << "ISBN" << setw(20) << "Author" << setw(35) << "Title"
            << setw(25) << "Publisher" << setw(7) << "Year" << setw(15) << "Genre"
            << setw(4) << "Qty" << setw(6) << "Price" << endl;
        cout << "________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________\n" << endl;

        cout << left << setw(15) << book[i].isbn
            << setw(20) << book[i].author
            << setw(35) << book[i].title
            << setw(25) << book[i].publisher
            << setw(7) << book[i].year
            << setw(15) << book[i].genre
            << setw(4) << book[i].quantity
            << setw(6) << book[i].price << endl << endl
            << "(Located at shelf " << book[i].location.shelf << " level " << book[i].location.level << ")" << endl << endl;
        cout << "________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________" << endl;

    }
    system("pause");
}


void search(BOOK_TYPE book[], int total_book)
{
    char keyword[55];
    char* substring;
    char tempKeyword[20];

    system("cls");
    // Prompt and get keyword to search student
    cout << "Enter ISBN, book title or author name to search: ";
    while (getchar() != '\n');
    cin.getline(keyword, 55);

    for (int i = 0; i < (int)strlen(keyword); i++)
    {
        keyword[i] = toupper(keyword[i]);   //capitalize all of the character
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < total_book; i++)
    {
        substring = strstr(book[i].isbn, keyword);
        if (substring)
        {
            cout << left << setw(15) << "ISBN" << setw(20) << "Author" << setw(35) << "Title"
                << setw(25) << "Publisher" << setw(7) << "Year" << setw(15) << "Genre"
                << setw(4) << "Qty" << setw(6) << "Price" << endl;
            cout << "________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________\n" << endl;

            cout << left << setw(15) << book[i].isbn
                << setw(20) << book[i].author
                << setw(35) << book[i].title
                << setw(25) << book[i].publisher
                << setw(7) << book[i].year
                << setw(15) << book[i].genre
                << setw(4) << book[i].quantity
                << setw(6) << book[i].price << endl << endl
                << "(Located at shelf " << book[i].location.shelf << " level " << book[i].location.level << ")" << endl << endl;
            cout << "________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________" << endl;

        }

        else if (strstr(book[i].author, keyword) != 0)
        {
            cout << left << setw(15) << "ISBN" << setw(20) << "Author" << setw(35) << "Title"
                << setw(25) << "Publisher" << setw(7) << "Year" << setw(15) << "Genre"
                << setw(4) << "Qty" << setw(6) << "Price" << endl;
            cout << "________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________\n" << endl;

            cout << left << setw(15) << book[i].isbn
                << setw(20) << book[i].author
                << setw(35) << book[i].title
                << setw(25) << book[i].publisher
                << setw(7) << book[i].year
                << setw(15) << book[i].genre
                << setw(4) << book[i].quantity
                << setw(6) << book[i].price << endl << endl
                << "(Located at shelf " << book[i].location.shelf << " level " << book[i].location.level << ")" << endl << endl;
            cout << "________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________" << endl;

        }
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Here is my book list I'm having in text file:

```
9781785785719,Yasha Levine,Surveillance Valley,Icon Books,2019,57.95,3,1,1,Political Science
9780241976630,John Maeda,How to Speak Machine,Portfolio UK,2019,89.95,2,1,1,Non-Fiction
9781119055808,Andre De Vries,R For Dummies,John Wiley,2015,107.77,4,1,2,Design
9780062018205,Dan Ariely,Predictably Irrational,Harper Collins,2010,39.90,2,1,1,Legal opinion
9780008327613,John Waish,The Globalist,Harper Collins,2019,109.90,2,1,1,Non-Fiction
9780525538349,John Doerr,Measure What Matters,Penguin LCC,2018,86.95,2,1,2,Management
9780807092156,Viktor Frankl,Man's Search for Meaning,Random House,2019,49.90,3,1,3,Biography
9780809875214,John Wick,The Assasinate of a Gang,Tree Production,2014,39.00,4,2,2,Fiction
9788373191723,J.R.R Tolkien,The Lord of the Rings,Allen & Unwin,1954,120.45,6,3,1,Fantasy Adventure
9783791535661,Lewis Carroll,Alice's Adventure in Wonderland,Macmillan,1865,100.25,5,3,2,Fantasy Fiction
9781517322977,Mikhail Bulgakov,The Master and Margarita,Penguin Books,1967,125.00,7,3,3,Romance Novel
9780676516197,Vladmir Nabokov,Lolita,Olympia Press,1955,98.25,3,3,1,Tragicomedy
9781095627242,Anna Sewell,Black Beauty,The Jarrold Group,1877,60.25,2,3,2,Fiction Novel
9788497592581,Umberto Eco,The Name of the Rose,Bompiani,1980,45.65,7,1,3,Historical Fiction
9780545790352,J.K.Rowling,Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone,Arthur A. Levine,2015,44.87,1,3,1
```

I manage to only output until John Wick (8th line from text file) when user prompt "1" at the menu to show book list.

Comment: 100 chars are not enough.

Comment: 100 chars ought to be enough for anybody ;)

Comment: @500 I think you're thinking 640K.

Comment: YOU'RE RIGHT, it's fixed... but hang on, when I added until 16 books, temp[1000] doesn't work as well.. it reads in until the 15th book...

Comment: One, and probably the biggest, reason why using `char` arrays as strings in C++ is frowned on. The tools you are using at least prevent utter disasters like buffer overflows, `std::istream::getline` places the stream in fail state if it cannot read the whole  line, so your loop exits.

Comment: Ohh..I see it right now.. and in the meantime I've entered one element less in my text file. Thanks after all.

Comment: Recommendation: Change `input.getline(temp, 100, '\n');` into `input.getline(temp, sizeof(temp), '\n');` This makes it easier to change the size of `temp`. You only need to make the change in one spot, and that's the definition of `temp`. Otherwise there s always the risk you'll leave a 100 in the way somewhere.

Comment: @user4581301 Thank you! It really help much reducing my work :)